# jquery panel with listview only open once on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, listview, jquery-mobile, panel

I'm using jquery mobile 1.3.1, and dynamically append list elements to a unordered list in a jquery panel. The first time I open the panel everything works fine, but when I close it and try to open it again, it will not show. But I can still click on the screen where I know the list elements are in the panel, and do stuff. The panel is just not showing. If I do click on the list elements, the panel shows quickly before it close and disappear. If I empty my unordered list and append the list elements again, the panel will then show when I open it, but again only once. This is however just a iOS issue, on android it works perfectly. So please help, I can't understand what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsScript/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsScript/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssScript/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />

<div id="mainMenu" style="display:none;" >

<!--Left Panel-->
<div data-role="panel" id="yourTurnPanel" data-display="overlay"  data-theme="a">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="navbar-header" id="yourTurnDiv">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Your Turn</h4>
            </div>
            <ul id="yourTurnList" data-role="listview"  >
            </ul>
        </div><!--/nav_name-->
    </div><!--/nav_profile-->
</div><!-- /panel -->
</div>
```

Here I empty and append the list

```
  var makeList = function(){
 $('#yourTurnList').empty();
   $('#yourTurnList').append('<li data-rel="close" data-icon="false"  data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn"><img src="'+picURL+'" class="ui-li-thumb ui-corner-tl"/> <div>  Player <br> Round</div></li>');
  }

// the method that opens the panel
 $("#yourTurn").click(function() {
   $("#yourTurnPanel").panel("open" , null); // works only once after appending the list elements
 });
```

Sorry for the ugly code!!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I dont think that is possible, because it works fine on everything except iphone...

Comment: You can visit jsFiddle on an iphone. So make a fiddle, navigate to it on the iphone, and if it exhibits the problem, post the fiddle in your question.

Comment: I did a quick fix and appended a new list element and removed it 0.4 seconds after. That made my panel open again... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding a list element to the list and remove it 0.4 seconds after. Then everything worked fine even on iphone. It's a quick fix, but it work!